# htaccess issue with underscore in folder name

Tags: .htaccess

I am getting Internal server error while using below line in htaccess

```
RewriteRule !^([a-z0-9-]+)($|/) /user_videos/%2%{REQUEST_URI} [PT,L]
```

While when I use:

```
RewriteRule !^([a-z0-9-]+)($|/) /uservideos/%2%{REQUEST_URI} [PT,L]
```

It works.

But I have **user_videos** directory in server.

Please let me know what is the issue while using underscore in folder name?

And how can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` instead of `[a-z0-9-]`.
This should make underscores work.

So the following should work:

```
RewriteRule !^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)($|/) /user_videos/%2%{REQUEST_URI} [PT,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with underscore. It seems to be a special value, in Mod_reWrite, but can be escaped with a back slash so:

`RewriteRule !^([a-z0-9-]+)($|/) /user\_videos/%2%{REQUEST_URI} [PT,L]`

should work, although at this point in time I can't test that.

Comment: I tried using above code using back slash, but same issue again :(